# Override Clone() in custom event for AS3... need help

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a custom even class which is pretty basic. But when calling an event and then relaying that event to another class I have encountered the "cannot transform thisEvent into thisOtherEvent" error.

I realize this is because I needed to override the Clone function in my custom event like so:

```
package com
{

 import flash.disply.*;
 import flash.events.Event;

 public class MyCustomEvents extends Event
 {

  public static const SOME_EVENT:String = "some_event";
  public var info:Object;

  public function MyCustomEvents($type:String, $info:Object,$bubbles:Boolean = false, $cancelable:Boolean = false)
  {

   super($type, $bubbles, $cancelable);
   this.info = $info;

  }

  public override function clone():Event {
   return new MyCustomEvents($type, $bubbles, $cancelable);
  }

 }
}
```

However I am still getting this error when I dispatch the event.  Anything else I might be missing?

here is the error:
`TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert com.greensock.events::TransformEvent@d8df709 to com.customEvents.MyCustomEvents.`

I tried casting the event in the code like so:

```
var deleteImgEvent:MyCustomEvent = new MyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvents.IMAGE_DELETE, {imgData: getImg}, true, false); this.dispatchEvent(deleteImgEvent as MyCustomEvents);
```

Still no luck.

UPDATE:

Ok, seems like the problem is in the greensock Transform library. When the event handler for my custom event is called, I run a function of the TransformManager class.

```
_manager.deleteSelection();
```

Inside that class it dispatched a TransformEvent.  Not sure why, but it is reading that delete event as a MyCustomEvent.

Comment: Where is the error actually located? Your `clone()` override is mostly correct (with the exception of needing to pass the "info" parameter to the constructor in your `clone()` function, as Patrick metions below). Are you trying to assign the result of the `clone()` function to a variable of type `MyCustomEvents`? If so you will need to cast the result of the `clone()` function.

Comment: Ok, So I added in the $info variable and was still getting this error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert com.greensock.events::TransformEvent@d8df709 to com.customEvents.MyCustomEvent.

I tried casting the event in the code like so:

var deleteImgEvent:MyCustomEvent = new MyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvent.IMAGE_DELETE, {imgData: getImg}, true, false);
   this.dispatchEvent(deleteImgEvent as MyCustomEvent);

still no luck.

Comment: spelling error: 'disply'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @usage
 * var myEvent:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.EVENT_TYPE_A, { integerRelatedToEvent: 5, stringRelatedToEvent: 'easy' });
 * addEventListener(CustomEvent.EVENT_TYPE_A, traceCustomEvent);
 * dispatch(myEvent);
 * function traceCustomEvent ($e:CustomEvent):void {
 *  trace($e.type);
 * }
 */
package {
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEvent extends Event {
        // Types:
        public static const EVENT_TYPE_A:String = 'CustomEvent.EVENT_TYPE_A';
        public static const EVENT_TYPE_B:String = 'CustomEvent.EVENT_TYPE_B';
        // Components:
        private var _customDatum:Object;
        public function get customDatum ():Object { return _customDatum; }


        public function CustomEvent ($type:String, $customDatum:Object) {
            super($type);
            _customDatum = $customDatum;
        }

        public override function clone ():Event {
            return new CustomEvent(type, _customDatum);
        }
    }
}
```

> *"When creating your own custom Event
>   class, you must override the inherited
>   Event.clone() method in order for it
>   to **duplicate the properties of your
>   custom class**. If you do not set all
>   the properties that you add in your
>   event subclass, those properties will
>   not have the correct values when
>   listeners handle the redispatched
>   event."*

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.events;
{
import flash.events.Event;
public class XMLLoaderEvent extends Event
{
    public static const XML_LOADED:String = "XML_Loaded";
    public var data:*;
    public var properties:Object;

    public function XMLLoaderEvent( type:String,_data:*,bubbles:Boolean = false,cancelable:Boolean = false):void
    {
        super( type, bubbles, cancelable );
        data = _data;
    }

    // Override clone
    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new XMLLoaderEvent( type, data, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's it but you have an extra parameter `$info:Object` into your custom event, but you don't pass it in your clone contructor.

```
return new MyCustomEvents(type, info, bubbles, cancelable);
```

Comment: nope, I tried that, still getting the same error. Everywhere I read says that is all I need to do, but still not working.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the clone function to return a MyCustomEvents type. Not an Event type. And you need to add the info parameter as stated by the previous poster.

```
package com {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MyCustomEvents extends Event {

    public static const SOME_EVENT:String = "some_event";
    public var info:Object;

        public function MyCustomEvents($type:String, $info:Object,$bubbles:Boolean = false, $cancelable:Boolean = false) {
            super($type, $bubbles, $cancelable);
            this.info = $info;
        }
        public override function clone():MyCustomEvents {
            return new MyCustomEvents(this.type, this.info, this.bubbles, this.cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because you are overriding the Event clone() not the custom event clone. When I do this  I get a incompatible override.